# Prism Navigation Not Working In New Window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

Edit: Please see my comment below - the code itself seems to be correct (at least the Prism region code) but navigation in the new window instance is still not working.

To start off with, here is the issue I'm having...
I have a main window with a menu bar that switches views in the main window to take the user to different screens. This is all working great.

So I thought today that I would add a 'first time user' screen to handle all the initial setup for the application. This is a new window that will pop up if certain first time properties haven't been set and welcome the new user, get the initial setup complete, etc. I wanted to have navigation on this new window in a new region (just next and back buttons that take the user through the setup).

I thought this would be easy but after 3 hours of floundering and searching the darkest corners of the web I am still very confused - I also looked at Brian Lagunas' Pluralsight videos on MVVM but nothing I have tried to apply is working to setup navigation on the new window.

The content region for the main window is named "ContentRegion" and the content region for the new window is named "SetupRegion".

All views are registered in the bootstrapper like so:

```
        // All views must be registered.
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Home>( "Home" );
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Index>( "Index" );
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Settings>( "Settings" );
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<FirstTimeSetupWelcomeScreen>( "WelcomeScreen" );
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<FirstTimeSetupScreen2>( "FirstTimeSetupScreen2" );
```

Here is how the new window is being instantiated currently, from the main window:

```
    public MainWindowViewModel(IRegionManager _regionManager, EventAggregator _eventAggregator)
    {
        eventAggregator = _eventAggregator;
        regionManager = _regionManager;

        NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Navigate);

        // Set the default view to the home screen
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegion", typeof(FirstTimeSetupWelcomeScreen));

        // Check to see if program is in first time run or not
        if ((ConfigurationManager.GetSection("SaveLocationsGroup/Locations") as IndexLocationsSection).SaveLocation.Location == "")
        {           
            var firstTimeWindow = new FirstTime();

            firstTimeWindow.Show();

            // Set the default view to the welcome screen on new window
            regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("SetupRegion", typeof(FirstTimeSetupWelcomeScreen));
        }
    }
```

In the XAML for the new window, the content control is setup like this:

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="SetupRegion" />
</Grid>
```

I have tested by replacing the code in the Navigate command on the main window and having it to navigate to the new user controls, showing them in the main window and that works.

However, in the new window they are not and I can't seem to figure out why. I have also tested to see if the button in the first/default user control view model is firing correctly and it is - for reference, here is that Navigate command code:

```
    private void Navigate(string uri)
    {
        // WriteLine command to test the button firing
        Console.WriteLine(uri);
        regionManager.RequestNavigate("SetupRegion", uri);
    }
```

Lastly I've placed the first view inside the main window and it seems to fire correctly, changing the content in the main window - I just can't get it to work or anything to work on the new window at all no matter how I try it. I'm assuming that there is something that I don't know that has to do with either navigation on new instances of windows (aside from the main window) or having to do with containers and new windows but I haven't been able to figure out what. Thank you guys for all of your assistance as always.

Comment: In fact I just tested by making the new window the main window in the bootstrapper and the navigation in the new window seems to be coded properly - Is navigation in prism limited to one window instance or do I need to do something special/different to get what I am trying to do to work?

Answer (score 0):

It turn out Brian Lagunas has a course on multiple shells I should hopefully be able to use to accomplish what I need. I will attempt to use it.